# Unable to install python2.7-dev due to unmet dependencies Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I  am unable  to install python-dev becasue  of  unment  dependancies. How  can I  get  around this? Deleting python is  not  an option and  I  cant  got  back to python2.6-dev as  it  cant  be  found.

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  python-dev : Depends:
>   python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.3) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable
>   to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So try python2.7-dev

sudo apt-get  install python2.7-dev

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  python2.7-dev :
>   Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be
>   installed
>                    Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Finally  check the  cache

```
apt-cache policy python python-dev
```

> Candidate: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
>         Version table:
>        *** 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
>               500 http://ftp.antik.sk/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
>               100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>
> ```
> python-dev:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
>   Version table:
>      2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
>         500 http://ftp.antik.sk/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
> foo@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ apt-cache policy python python-dev
>
> python:
>   Installed: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
>   Candidate: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
>   Version table:
>  *** 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
>         500 http://ftp.antik.sk/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>
> python-dev:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
>   Version table:
>      2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
>         500 http://ftp.antik.sk/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
> ```

Comment: I googled the error message [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages] and the first hit is:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-fix-broken-package-904637/